# how to count field with condition by spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe, there is a enum field(value are 0 or 1) named `A`, another one field `B`, I would like to implement below scenario:

```
if `B` is null:
   count(when `A` is 0) and set a column name `xx` 
   count(when `A` is 1) and set a column name `yy` 
if `B` is not null:
   count(when `A` is 0) and set a column name `zz` 
   count(when `A` is 1) and set a column name `mm`
```

how can I do it by spark scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to conditionally populate columns in this way, however the final output DataFrame requires an expected schema.

Assuming all of the scenarios you detailed are possible in one DataFrame, I would suggest creating each of the four columns: `"xx"`, `"yy"`, `"zz"` and `"mm"` and **conditionally populating them**.

In the below example I've populated the values with either `"found"` or `""`, primarily to make it easy to see where the values are populated. Using `true` and `false` here, or another enum, would likely make more sense in the real world.

Starting with a DataFrame (since you didn't specify the type that `"B"` is I have gone for a `Option[String]` (nullable) for this example:

```scala
val df = List(
    (0, None),
    (1, None),
    (0, Some("hello")),
    (1, Some("world"))
).toDF("A", "B")
     
 df.show(false)
```

gives:

```
+---+-----+
|A  |B    |
+---+-----+
|0  |null |
|1  |null |
|0  |hello|
|1  |world|
+---+-----+
```

and to create the columns:

```scala
df
    .withColumn("xx", when(col("B").isNull && col("A") === 0, "found").otherwise(""))
    .withColumn("yy", when(col("B").isNull && col("A") === 1, "found").otherwise(""))
    .withColumn("zz", when(col("B").isNotNull && col("A") === 0, "found").otherwise(""))
    .withColumn("mm", when(col("B").isNotNull && col("A") === 1, "found").otherwise(""))
    .show(false)
```

gives:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|A  |B    |xx   |yy   |zz   |mm   |
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|0  |null |found|     |     |     |
|1  |null |     |found|     |     |
|0  |hello|     |     |found|     |
|1  |world|     |     |     |found|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```